# How to test association extension logic in rails with minimal DB overhead

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, associations

I am a fan of using mocks and stubs everywhere I can to keep my specs running quickly.
I'm kind of stumped as to how I might do this to test the find_special method in the following:

```
  has_many :foos do 
    def find_special
      if proxy_owner.baz
        ... find stuff
      else
        ... find other stuff
      end
    end
  end
```

I wouldn't mind using the :extend => module syntax for this, but I don't think it makes a difference.

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking how to stub a method on the `proxy_owner`? In this case isn't it the object which you're calling `foos` on?

```
# in Mocha
item.stubs(:baz).returns(true)
item.foos.find_special # => find stuff
item.stubs(:baz).returns(false)
item.foos.find_special # => find other stuff
```

**This is untested** but maybe it will get you close.

Comment: But I would still need to make a bunch of Foo objects and save them to the database before this test, right? 
I'm looking for a way where I could test that the find_special method causes Foo.find to be called with the right parameters, without actually needing to run the query against the database.

Comment: Shorter version: I know how to test this with factories/fixtures - I want to see if I can do it without them.

Comment: You can build item and foos in memory: Item.new and item.foos.build. No need to touch the database.